# Sum of multiple loaded dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $n$ dice with $m$ sides. The $i^{th}$ dice will show value $0 \leq x_i \leq m-1$ with probability $0 \leq D_i(x_i) \leq 1$. What is the probability that the sum of the dice equals $\alpha$?

Is there some approximation for $P(\alpha)$?

Comment: Since you subscripted "$D$" with the index of the dice, does that mean each die might have a different distribution?

Comment: You can obtain the exact probability function by discrete convolution.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Not sure about a precise analytical solution.

However for large m there is a good approximation indeed.

The random variables $X_i$ where $i\in [0, m-1]$ where $X_i$ is the probability distribution of the $i^{th}$ dice are identical (each having the same mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$) and independent. We can hence apply the theorem of the central limit which states that

$$S_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}X_i$$ is approximated by $\mathcal{N}(m \mu, m \sigma^2)$  when m is large.